# How can I wrap Meteor.Error method?

Tags: javascript, meteor, winston

I would like to log `Meteor.Error` messages to Winston but I can't find a good way to wrap the function `Meteor.Error`.

Here is the code I found on the internet :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    logger.info("OVERRIDING METEOR FUNCTION");
    // Override Meteor.Error function to log it
    const errorFunc = Meteor.Error;
    Meteor.Error = function(error, reason, details) {
        console.log("TEST");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(reason);
        console.log(details);
        logger.error('Error: ' + error, {
            error: error,
            reason: reason,
            details: details,
            stack: Error().stack,
            tags: ['error']
        });
        errorFunc.call(this, error, reason, details);
    };
    throw new Meteor.Error("PATATRA", "PTOEOEORORE");
}
```

Winston log the error but after the call to the original `Meteor.Error` the method fails with this message:

```
(STDERR) /home/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.15l6i5x.c6ri++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
(STDERR)                        throw(ex);
(STDERR)                        ^
(STDERR) [object Object]
```

I would like to find a way to wrap properly the `Meteor.error` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think just removing the `throw new Meteor.Error("PATATRA", "PTOEOEORORE");` This will still execute the default `new Meteor.Error()` code.